# Does the Tanach tell us 36 times to love the stranger?

Tags: tanach, love

If you Google "love the stranger 36 times" you get 93,100,000 returns.  Indeed, I've been hearing this line for ages:

> "36 times in the Tanach God tells us to love the stranger." [Bava Metzia 59b]

I was never able to find a list of these 36 quotes.  Can anybody help?

[Here, I'll start:  "**וַאֲהַבְתֶּ֖ם אֶת־הַגֵּ֑ר** – You shall love the stranger." [Deut. 10:19]   :-)  ]

Comment: https://seforimblog.com/2019/07/dont-oppress-the-ger/

Comment: Bava Mezi'a 59b actually says: "תניא רבי אליעזר הגדול אומר מפני מה הזהירה תורה בל"ו מקומות ואמרי לה במ"ו מקומות בגר מפני שסורו רע" (in [translation](http://halakhah.com/babamezia/babamezia_59.html#PARTb): "It has been taught: R. Eliezer the Great said: Why did the Torah warn against [the wronging of] a proselyte in thirty-six, or as others say, in forty-six, places? Because he has a strong inclination to evil")

Comment: Re: Google searching "love the stranger 36 times": If I [search with quotes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22love+the+stranger+36+times%22), I get 220 results, and if I [add  quotes between 'stranger' and '36'](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22love+the+stranger%22+%2236+times%22), I get 3,840 results.

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Good find.  It seems to at least establish the fact that there is no "canonical" list in the Sources.

Comment: You might want to look at this Shita https://www.sefaria.org/Shita_Mekubetzet_on_Bava_Metzia.59b.10?lang=bi before compiling a list.