# If the Torah tells us 36 times to love the stranger where did the sephardic minhag of not marrying geirim come from?

Tags: marriage, conversion-to-judaism, geirim, sephardim, syrian

To my understanding, the Syrian Jewish community of New York adheres to an "Edict" forbidding marriage to a convert. If the Torah tells us 36 times to love the convert where did this communal decree come from?

We know that moshiach will descend from Ruth. So many others in Jewish history are geirim. Was there an event or specific situation that prompted this community to not allow marriage to geirim. Does anyone know the background on that? Thank you.

Comment: how do you know  there is a sephardic minhag of not marrying geirim?

Comment: This is only a thing in [much of] the Syrian community, but anyway loving them doesn't mean you have to marry them.

Comment: Yes i heard the same about Syrian community, and the reason I was told was that wealthy syrians would pressure the rabbis to convert non Jewish women, they wanted to marry, even though the reason for the conversion was only to permit the marriage and not becouse they purely want to be Jewish

Comment: @double AA  the torah says it 36 times to emphasize to treat a ger exactly as one would treat a jew. and in my view that would include marriage. further, if moshiach descends from a ger, that too would be an incentive to accept them fully and that would include marriage.

Comment: @hazpriz thank you for your reasonable response.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's repeated it to emphasize that you should love them, not to emphasize that you should treat them exactly as a Jew.

Comment: You should update your question to reflect the fact this is true only for a small portion of the Sephardic community - it is absolutely not correct for the majority of it. Treating Sephardim as a united group is unawareness of the breadth of customs across Morocco, Tunisia, Algeria, Egypt, Turkey, Yemen, Iran, etc.

Comment: @double AA and love means what? saying "not my daughter"? I have spoken to several geirim who told me that the community welcomed them, taught them torah etc. but when it came to shidduchim they all said "not my daughter". How is that loving the stranger? maybe the Torah's 36 warnings is not enough.

Comment: @shoshana I'm not married to an Italian. Does that mean I don't love Italians? Welcoming them and teaching them Torah is how most people love most other people. Very few of the people you love do you marry.

Comment: @shoshana "_I have spoken to several geirim who told me that the community welcomed them, taught them torah etc. but when it came to shidduchim they all said 'not my daughter'_ ". (1) In all these cases, were only Sephardic communities involved? (2) Did any of the people, who said "not my daughter" to _geirim_, respond differently to, let's say, _ba'alei teshuvah_?

Comment: does https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5962/motivation-for-disallowing-conversions answer your question?

Comment: Jews could marry converts in Egypt, where I grew up.

Comment: @double AA.... defining love as teaching torah is misguided. though it can be, it is not exclusively so ... if someone is hungry love means giving them food. if someone is sick, love means caring for them. and if someone is looking for a shidduch love means giving them a chance whether they are a ger or a jew or an italian jew. Your non sequiturs lead me to believe you are okay with being prejudiced against people like Avraham Avinu, Ruth, etc... as long as you teach them Torah. which of course is ridiculous.

Comment: Attacking a straw man that love only entails teaching Torah is what's ridiculous. I definitely hold Ruth was a different status in some regards than a born Jew and Halacha backs me on that, no matter how many times it says "Love Them" in the verses.

Comment: @tamir evan.... i didn't ask but i assume some would respond the same way and some would not. The Torah also does not single out BTs 36 times bec. they have a jewish history and relatives. I've befriended geirim. BT stories do not rival what geirim are put through. but seem okay with that as long as "you teach Torah". I vehemently disagree. It's a HUGE chillul Hashem to talk the talk but not walk the walk. You don't have to marry anyone but you have to give them an equal chance and sadly many people don't.

Comment: Double AA When you say "different" I assume you mean "lower" but Ruth the Moabite merited to be the ancestor of King David and Moshiach. Can you say the same? I won't be responding further. You need to start incorporating Torah into your every day life instead of patting yourself on the back for studying it and then leaving it on the page.

Comment: Related: "[Does the Tanach tell us 36 times to love the stranger](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109677/1368)"? (Spoiler: The torah doesn't actually _tell us to love_ the stranger 36 time, regardless of how [many on the internet might quote it that way](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22love+the+stranger+36+times%22), but rather [it _warns us regarding_ the stranger 36, or 46, times](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.59b.14?lang=bi&lang2=en).)

Comment: Sigh, the advantage of learning it before deciding what it means is you're more likely to get it right. Learn halacha. Don't just read the verses and guess how to apply it.